# How to switch font families in JavaFX via CSS without support of css string variables?

Tags: javafx, gluon

Assuming I do assign the font family I want to use for Latin languages via CSS to all of my UI controls via

control1.css:

```
.controlStyleClass > Label {
    -fx-font-family: 'MyLatinFont';
.controlStyleClass > Text {
    -fx-font-family: 'MyBoldLatinFont';
}
```

and want to switch to another font if the language of the application is changed to let's say Chinese. Instead of exchanging the style class definition for every single of my UI controls, it would be so easy if I could just define the font string via css variable:

control1.css:

```
.controlStyleClass > Label {
    -fx-font-family: selectedFont;
}
.controlStyleClass > Text {
    -fx-font-family: selectedBoldFont;
}
```

and later-on either assign 
latin.css:

```
* {
    selectedFont: 'MyLatinFont';
    selectedBoldFont: 'MyBoldLatinFont';
}
```

or chinese.css

```
* {
selectedFont: 'MyChineseFont';
    selectedBoldFont: 'MyBoldChineseFont';
}
```

as stylesheet to my application. Unfortunately, only css variables for numbers and colors seem to be supported by JavaFX so far. Does anyone have a good concept / workaround for this kind of font handling? I would really appreciate every single hint...!